# FullTextSqlQuery returning incorrect results

Tags: 2007, search, fulltextsqlquery

We are having usual behaviour with FullTextSqlQuery and wonder if anyone can help.

The following should return 3 records which represent 3 pages on the site with titles "Sample (test1)", "Sample (test2)", and "Sample (test3)".

```
SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path
FROM portal..scope()
WHERE ( ("SCOPE" = 'myScope') )  AND CONTAINS ('"sample"')
ORDER BY "Rank" DESC
```

For some reason this only yeilds 1 result, say "Sample (test3)".

If we change this to use a query as follows, then this also returns a single result. However this time the result is a different record, say "Sample (test3)", which proves more than 1 entry was indexed by the crawl.

```
SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path
FROM portal..scope()
WHERE ( ("SCOPE" = 'myScope') )  AND FREETEXT(defaultproperties, '"sample"')
ORDER BY "Rank" DESC
```

Why are these queries not returning all 3 results? We have tried setting *TrimDuplicates* to false but it makes no difference.

Comment: If you could move your comment about TrimDuplicates to an answer that would be great. Then we can mark this as answered :-)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How does the duplicate document is identified when we do a search?

Document similarity for purposes of identifying duplicates is based only on a hash of the content of the document.  No File properties (e.g. file name, type, author, create and modify dates) are input to this hash.  The MSSDuplicateHashes table in the SSP’s search database holds, for each document, all the 64bit hashes necessary to determine if one document is a near-duplicate of another.  This is read while doing a search if duplicate collapsing is enabled.

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/harikumh/archive/2008/11/14/some-interesting-facts-about-sharepoint-2007-search.aspx

Answer (score 0):

have you tried expanding the scope to 'All Sites'?

Comment: Actually it turns out that TrimDuplicates was causing the issue afterall, it wasn't deployed properly when we tested the setting the the first time around. I'm not sure why it would treat these 2 items as duplicates though, does it ignore content in braces?